# QGraphicsView scroll bar policy not working as expected

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have a QGraphicsView with a vertical scroll bar policy of "ScrollBarAlwaysOff". The problem is that when I adjust the size of the view (via a QSplitter or just by adjusting the size of the window), a blank space will often appear on the right side of the view. Here's an example with a red background and a black QGraphicsRectItem:

```
#include <QtGui>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow()
    {
        QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
        QRectF rect(-100, -100, 200, 200);
        QGraphicsRectItem *rectItem = new QGraphicsRectItem(rect);
        rectItem->setBrush(QBrush(Qt::black));
        scene->addItem(rectItem);
        scene->setSceneRect(rect); //commenting this out doesn't make a difference

        QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
        view->setBackgroundBrush(QBrush(Qt::red));
        view->setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorViewCenter);
        view->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
        view->setScene(scene);

        setCentralWidget(view);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Here is what the problem looks like:

[image: image of the problem]

How can I fix this?

EDIT: Click here to make the picture a bit larger: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeWHJ.png

Comment: Unfortunately I can't reproduce this behavior in PyQt. Using PyQt 4.9.1 and Qt 4.8.1. For me, I get constant black when its smaller than the QGraphicsItem size. And obviously, red when it is larger than the QGraphicItem size

Comment: @jdi I appreciate you checking into it. I'm using 4.8.0. I'll update to 4.8.1 and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a try and find that if you change your rectangle to (0, 0, 300, 300), it works as desired. It seems `QGraphicsView` has problem handling scroll bar update with negative top-left scene rect. You should file a bug report to Qt.

Comment: What version of Qt did you test this on? I did not see this issue at all in 4.8.1

Comment: That does fix it for me. Very weird. As @jdi mentioned, it could be a version issue. I'll report it as a bug (and here) if it remains once I update.

Comment: Yes. It's in 4.8.1 and 5.0 alpha right now. At least on the C++ binding.

Comment: I guess the python bindings somehow address the issue. Strange though since its still using the same c++ underneath